# Delayed messages in JMS queue

Tags: jms, message-queue, weblogic-10.x

I have a question about a delay that happens intermittently in one queue. I'm using JMS over Weblogic 10.0.

So, the client sends a message to the server through the queue called RequestQueue.
The server responses to the client through the queue called ResponseQueue.
The response message is a 12-character Java String, a simple answer.

The average response time is 3 seconds. But, sometimes the response message is delayed and it arrives in... 2 minutes! The message seems to remain in the queue.
There is no error in logs, the response message always arrives, but about 10%, this delay happens, and I don't know why. I can't identify any pattern that explain this situation.

Could you tell me any suggestion about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing i would check is whether the messages are produced later, or the messaging system does delay the messages after the sent operation. Therefor you can check the *JMSTimestamp* field in the Message header. Maybe you can just log the JMSTimestamp file of the Request and the Response message then you can focus your analysing on the part of the system where the delay seems to occur.